# How to test html render in razor page

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to test html page of my razor page. This is my frontend:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
}

<div class="container col-xxl-8 px-4 py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center g-5 py-5">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold lh-1 mb-3">
                Les Amitiés Spirituelles
            </h1>
            <p class="lead">Groupe de Québec</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to test if "Les Amitiés Spirituelles" is written correctly.
I have try this (IndexTest.cs):

```
public class IndexTest
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory;

    public IndexTest(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task GivenPage_WhenLoad_ASISWritten()
    {
        var client = factory.CreateClient();
        var html = await client.GetHtmlAsync("/");
        var header = html.QuerySelector("h1");
        NUnit.Framework.Assert.Equals("Les Amitiés Spirituelles", header.Text());
    }
...
```

For that I have created that class:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom;

namespace as_quebec_test
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<IDocument> GetHtmlAsync(this HttpClient client, string urlPath)
        {
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(urlPath);
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
            var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(response));
            return document;
        }
    }
}
```

but I got the error:

> OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found

Do you know how to test it? I'm in .net 6.

Comment: What is OneTimeSetUp

Comment: Don't know exactly what it is...

Comment: is https://bunit.dev/ helpful?

Comment: NUnit does not support injecting, use a default ctor for IndexTest

Comment: How would you do that? I am in Razor and I should inject the factory, because I need it. Can you show how you would test my h1 tag?